# How to directly assign a struct into an array?

Tags: c, struct

```
// Structure to store tuples of data
struct tuple {
    double val; 
    int source; // 1 or 2, as in sample1 or sample2
};

// Assume both samples are of length n
double function(double* sample1, double* sample2, int n) {  
    struct tuple data[n*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2) {
        struct tuple t = {sample1[i], 1};
        data[i] = t;
        t = {sample2[i], 2};
        data[i+1] = t;

    // more processing
    return value;   
}
```

I want to avoid declaring `struct tuple t` inside the loop, since I shouldn't need to, but I can't figure out a way to declare and initialize a `struct` on the right hand side of an assignment. Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your sole intent is to avoid a named `t` variable, you can dispense with it for a pair of [compound literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
data[i]     = (struct tuple){sample1[i], 1};
data[i + 1] = (struct tuple){sample2[i], 2};
```

It should satisfy any desire for terseness. Bear in mind you need to enable C11 (or C99) support for it to work. <sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - That variable length array kinda indicates you already do have it enabled.</sub>

Comment: I will still have to declare `struct tuple` and define (as done in my sample code) before using it in this way, correct?

Comment: @kingledion - I'm not sure I follow. `struct tuple` is a type. Of course you need to have a definition present if you want to use it.